# vscode: Open a file in VSCODE from a string

Tags: vscode-remote

I have custom code on a php project.

> $txt_choice  =
> dform::load_layout('ca/example.php',array('var1'=>true));

How can i open the file "ca/example.php" on a cmd + p (or double click for example) using vscode ?

Comment: I am looking for the same feature.